# how to open MY COMPUTER and control panel from java code?

Tags: java

I am **trying to open mycomputer and control panel from java code.**I tried all the solution of related questions on stack overflow but find no appropriate answer.

I am also trying to perform following actions:-

1. **Delete temporary file** from java code.
2. **control volume of laptop**/pc from java code.
3. **open default browser** from java code.
   please help me out as soon as possible.
   thanks in advance.

Comment: These are very unrelated things. You may have better luck asking just a single question at a time. In terms of opening "My Computer", this is really an application called "explorer" (in Windows; on Mac OS X, the equivalent is "Finder", and on Linux, there are applications like "gnome", "kde", and other Window managers for this). If you want to launch that UI, you need to invoke that particular program (assuming that this was your goal as opposed to, for example, displaying a selector to the user for selecting a file ... which can be done in a more standard manner).

Comment: Any reason you are using Java to do all those? Windows script is much easier.

Comment: yes there is reason, I am trying to perform all these mentioned above from android phone( making socket connection between pc and android and server runs on java that is listening for android client)

Comment: can we refresh system (F5) from java code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the following code

To open control panel

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start control");
```

To open My Computer

```
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start explorer");
```

To Open browser

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start chrome.exe");
```

Comment: new Robot().keyPress() & new Robot().keyRelease() event allows you to press and release all the keys which is there in your keyboard. Also Robot class allows to move mouse as well as click buttons of the mouse.

Comment: suppose I want to close/minimize / maximize the focused window from java code, can i do this? focused window means it can be browser or video or any thing that is on top of stack of opened programmes

Comment: yes, all what you need it that Robot r=new Robot(); r.keyPress(KeyEvent.ALT);r.keyPress(KeyEvent.SPACE);r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.ALT);r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.SPACE);Then to minimize r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_N);

Comment: are making jarvis or what as you are aking all this kind of thing like to automate everything

Comment: I am creating socket and control all these events from android phone where pc act as server and java code run on pc itself

Answer (score 1):

For your third point you can use:

Imports

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
```

Code

```
if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.example.com"));
        System.out.println("Browser geöffnet");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not with the Desktop class, but I don´t know any other class for refeshing the browser

Answer (score 1):

The library [java.awt.Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) might help you in some way. With this library you are able to press and release keyboard hits.

Sure you have to develop a little bit. But your are able to do many things with keyPress.

If you want to open the explorer you need to press `windows key` **and** `e`

```
  Robot robot = new Robot();

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);

        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_E);
```

Here a simple example:

```
try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        // Simulate a mouse click
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

        // Simulate a key press
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);

} catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @sakshamagarwal Using this robot library you can simulate the F5 hit on the keyboard: `robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F5); robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F5);`

Answer (score 0):

you Can use Something like this.It is possible with Java Desktop class

```
Desktop desktop = null;
  if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
  }

 Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("c:\\"));
```

Read Documentation for more depth:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html

Another Consideration Can be

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ExecuteShellComand {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecuteShellComand obj = new ExecuteShellComand();

    String domainName = "google.com";

    //in windows
    //String command = "control panel";

    String output = obj.executeCommand(command);

    System.out.println(output);

}

private String executeCommand(String command) {

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = 
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();

}
```

}